# Sort multidimensional Array by date but only it's children

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i'm trying to sort the children of an array but failing miserably.. Problem is that only the children should get sorted/compared against another by their ['date']['form_date '] value, not the first layer of the array :(

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-07-07
                            [to_date] => 2018-07-07
                        )

                    [post] => Special: Pferdefotografie
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-07-21
                            [to_date] => 2018-07-21
                        )

                    [post] => Fotoexkursion Südafrika
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-07-21
                            [to_date] => 2018-07-21
                        )

                    [post] => Fotoexkursion Landschaftsfotografie
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-07-21
                            [to_date] => 2018-07-21
                        )

                    [post] => Bildaufbau und Komposition
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-07-22
                            [to_date] => 2018-07-22
                        )

                    [post] => Bildaufbau und Komposition
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-08-11
                            [to_date] => 2018-08-11
                        )

                    [post] => Bildaufbau und Komposition
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-08-04
                            [to_date] => 2018-08-04
                        )

                    [post] => Makrofotografie 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-08-26
                            [to_date] => 2018-08-26
                        )

                    [post] => Tierfotografie 2
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-08-19
                            [to_date] => 2018-08-19
                        )

                    [post] => Tierfotografie 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-09-15
                            [to_date] => 2018-09-15
                        )

                    [post] => Bildaufbau und Komposition
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-09-02
                            [to_date] => 2018-09-02
                        )

                    [post] => Makrofotografie 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [from_date] => 2018-09-01
                            [to_date] => 2018-09-01
                        )

                    [post] => Makrofotografie 1
                )

        )

)
```

I tried on using usort for comparing the dates, but i guess it fails because of the level of nesting!?

```
usort($events, function ($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a[0]['date']['from_date']) - strtotime($b[0]['date']['from_date']);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance for looking into this :)

Comment: (I guess) you want to loop through the top level of the array and `usort` each second-level independently (?).

Comment: because, its working off the `$events[0][0]['from_date']` and `$events[1][0]['from_date']` and so on in the loop

Comment: you should put all the second level elements into an array, then usort them.

Comment: Please offer ready-to-use input data so that volunteers don't have waste time reengineering your input array before they can begin work on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because your dates are in `Y-m-d` format, you don't need to bother converting them to timestamps -- just compare them as strings.  As deceze said, you just need to iterate the first level and remember to modify by reference (so that you aren't modifying a "copy" of the array).

Code:  (Demo: https://3v4l.org/AXsqR )

```
foreach ($array as &$set) {
    usort($set, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['date']['from_date'], $b['date']['from_date']);
    });
}
```